# ionic 3 phonegap-plugin-push plugin_not_installed

Tags: push-notification, ionic3, phonegap-plugin-push

i have to use the push notifications in my app so i followed this [tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) to add the ionic native push , when i run the app on android

the console prints this warning message "plugin_not_installed" 
i tried to remove the platform with **cordova platform remove android** and 
then reinstall it but nothing has changed and i'm still getting the same problem

this is the environment informations :

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.1
npm               : 3.5.2 
OS                : Linux 4.15
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/hamza/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1):

try android platform version 7.1.0

> ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0